# Mistake when printing a string using termcolor Python Module

Tags: python, printing, colors

I have installed this python module
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/termcolor

Using the example provided in the link, i tried to print a string in different ways as follows:

```
from termcolor import colored, cprint

text = colored(ship_row, 'red', attrs=['reverse', 'blink'])
print(text)

cprint(ship_row, 'green', 'on_red')
```

However, instead of printing the string with the desired colors, my output is:

```
[5m[7m[31m3[0m

[41m[32m3[0m
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this problem?

Comment: What terminal are you using? Are you sure it can handle colours?

Comment: I am using the python IDLE terminal

Answer (score 0):

You need to import colorama for termcolor to work with the windows terminal

```
from colorama import init
from termcolor import colored, cprint
init(convert = True)
cprint('Your Text', 'red')
```